# Graph mean and standard deviation

Tags: r, ggplot2

The source of this data is server performance metrics. The numbers I have are the mean (os_cpu) and standard deviation (os_cpu_sd). Mean clearly doesn't tell the whole story, so I want to add standard deviation. I started down the path of geom_errorbar, however I believe this is for standard error. What would be an accepted way to plot these metrics? Below is a reproducible example:

```
DF_CPU <- structure(list(end = structure(c(1387315140, 1387316340, 1387317540, 
   1387318740, 1387319940, 1387321140, 1387322340, 1387323540, 1387324740, 
   1387325940, 1387327140, 1387328340, 1387329540, 1387330740, 1387331940, 
   1387333140, 1387334340, 1387335540, 1387336740, 1387337940, 1387339140, 
   1387340340, 1387341540, 1387342740, 1387343940, 1387345140, 1387346340, 
   1387347540, 1387348740, 1387349940), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
   ), tzone = "UTC"), os_cpu = c(14.8, 15.5, 17.4, 15.6, 14.9, 14.6, 
     15, 15.2, 14.6, 15.2, 15, 14.5, 14.8, 15, 14.6, 14.9, 14.9, 14.4, 
     14.8, 14.9, 14.5, 15, 14.6, 14.5, 15.3, 14.6, 14.6, 15.2, 14.5, 
     14.5), os_cpu_sd = c(1.3, 2.1, 3.2, 3.3, 0.9, 0.4, 1.4, 1.5, 
        0.4, 1.6, 1, 0.4, 1.4, 1.4, 0.4, 1.3, 0.9, 0.4, 1.4, 1.3, 0.4, 
        1.7, 0.4, 0.4, 1.7, 0.4, 0.4, 1.7, 0.5, 0.4)), .Names = c("end", 
            "os_cpu", "os_cpu_sd"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
                5L, 9L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 25L, 29L, 33L, 37L, 41L, 45L, 49L, 53L, 
                57L, 61L, 65L, 69L, 73L, 77L, 81L, 85L, 89L, 93L, 97L, 101L, 
                  105L, 109L, 113L, 117L))

head(DF_CPU)
                   end os_cpu os_cpu_sd
1  2013-12-17 21:19:00   14.8       1.3
5  2013-12-17 21:39:00   15.5       2.1
9  2013-12-17 21:59:00   17.4       3.2
13 2013-12-17 22:19:00   15.6       3.3
17 2013-12-17 22:39:00   14.9       0.9

ggplot(data=DF_CPU, aes(x=end, y=os_cpu)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=os_cpu-os_cpu_sd,ymax=os_cpu+os_cpu_sd), alpha=0.2,color="red")
```

[image]

Per @ari-b-friedman suggestion, here's what it looks like with geom_ribbon():
[image]

Comment: I think you can use `geom_errorbar` just fine here, but since they're connected have you considered `geom_ribbon`? http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_ribbon.html

Comment: You can use `geom_errorbar` to plot anything: standard error, standard deviation, confidence interval, min/max, ... That's why figures need captions, which specify things like that.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman thanks, I added your example. Good suggestion.

Comment: @Roland also a good suggestion. I don't do enough captions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is largely about aesthetics, and so opinions will differ. Having said that there are some guidelines:

1. Emphasize what is important.
2. Provide a frame of reference if at all possible.
3. Avoid misleading scales or graphics.
4. Avoid unnecessary graphics.

So this code:

```
ggplot(data=DF_CPU, aes(x=end, y=os_cpu)) +
  geom_point(size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_line(linetype=2, colour="grey")+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=os_cpu-1.96*os_cpu_sd,ymax=os_cpu+1.96*os_cpu_sd), alpha=0.5,color="blue")+
  ylim(0,max(DF_CPU$os_cpu+1.96*DF_CPU$os_cpu_sd))+
  stat_smooth(formula=y~1,se=TRUE,method="lm",linetype=2,size=1)+
  theme_bw()
```

Produces this:
[image]

This graphic emphasizes that cpu utilization (??) over 20 min intervals did not deviate significantly from the average for the 9 hour period monitored. The reference line is average utilization. The error bars were replaced with `geom_linerange(...)` because the horizontal bars in `geom_errorbar(...)` add nothing and are distracting. Also, your original plot makes it seem that error is very large compared to actual utilization, which it isn't. I changed the range to `+/- 1.96*sd` because that more closely approximates 95% CL. Finally, the x- and y-axis labels need to be replaced with something descriptive, but I don't have enough information to do that.

Comment: you bring up some great points on my goals. I was trying to be concise with my question, but I think a bit more context would help. I'm not a statistician and one of my biggest academic regrets is not putting more time into my stats classes. Anyway, this is graph is part of a larger project I'm working on to characterize database performance. It's mostly in the context of "sizing" new systems to replace existing systems. I work for a large systems company and I'm working hard to improve our sizing accuracy. If we sell a system that's "too big", we've wasted our customers' money...

Comment: ... "too small" and we haven't actually solved their problems. So, this isn't a case where I believe we can develop a model for each customer. I've been focusing on the descriptive stats side of things and the actual data spans 8+ days. In this case, our mean is around 15% CPU utilization, with a max SD of around 23%. Sizing to the mean would be a bit low, so I would choose a value of say 23% to cover the peaks. SPECint benchmarks tell us comparative chip speeds, so 23% of 12 Intel Xeon Westmere Cores = n Intel Sandybridge Cores. Hope this helps put some context around my question.

Answer (score 2):

There's a designer's adage that "form follows function", and this should apply to graphics. What are you trying to do with your plots? What's the question you are trying to answer?

If it is "is cpu usage significantly decreasing with time?" then this plot will probably do and gives the answer "no". If it is "is the probability of exceeding 10s changing with time?" then you need to assume a model for your data (eg something as simple as Normal(os_cpu, os_cpu_sd)) and then plot exceedence (tail) probabilities.

Anyway, just plotting means and envelopes like you have done is always a fair start, and at least answers the questions "what does my data look like?" and "is anything obviously wrong?"

Comment: You had asked a similar contextual question to jlhoward . I added some context in a reply to his comment. To a statistician, this probably feels like amateur-hour. Sorry.